# Single executable jar for a multi-project maven project

Tags: maven, dependencies, executable-jar

I am trying to create a single executable jar out of a multi-project maven project.  Here is my project structure followed by what I tried to do with the maven assembly plugin. Will appreciate a lot of anybody can hint me about the solution (which would seem to me the most common ground, but I could not find in other discussion chains). Thanks!

The structure I have is (simplified):

myApp

```
…
  <groupId>myApp</groupId> <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>myApp</name>  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
…  
  <build>
     <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>  <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>

  <modules>
    <module>../m1</module> <!--  jar-->
    <module>../m2</module> <!--  war -->
    <module>../subAppPomAggregationProject</module>
  </modules>  

  <dependencies>
…
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried to add the below plugin to the myApp pom file:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
 <configuration>
   <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
      <archive>
         <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.mypath.Main</mainClass>
         </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
 </configuration>
 <executions>
    <execution>
       <id>make-assembly</id>
       <phase>package</phase>
       <goals>
           <goal>single</goal>
       </goals>
    </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Of course it did not create a jar for MyApp, but it did create a what seemed to as an aggregated jar in each module (!), although not really with all the dependency.

I also tried to create another uber-project (jar) with either module or dependency of MyApp – did not work either. Was I supposed to list in the uber-jar all the modules imported to MyApp (along with modules imported into subAppPomAggregationProject)? Did not try that, but if so – what is then the purpose of the pom aggregator, and why use a two-stage compilation/aggregation approach?

I could not try the maven-shade-plugin (not sure if it would help), because it requires maven 3 and I am currently using 2.2.1 (would not want to upgrade and shake things right before my near milestone…).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an older version if the shade plugin. 
Version 1.7.1 is the last release of shade that works on Maven 2.x and it will work for creating an executable jar file... The syntax should be pretty much the same, the switch of major version number was to indicate the switch to Maven 3 as a requirement.

Comment: Do I add this plugin in MyApp pom.xml (pom packaging), or do I create another project (say myappjar) in which I place the plugin? If the latter, do I simply put a dependency of MyApp in myappjar pom.xml?

Comment: One artifact per module. So don't hijack your aggregator (also the parent must be built before the child so couldn't have that way even if you wanted to)

Comment: When I added the shade plugin to MyApp pom.xml I got the following error: [INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing null with /home/.../MyApp/target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.pom
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] Error creating shaded jar: null.   So obviously that solution does not work. Will try the second option.

Comment: When I added the shade plugin to MyApp pom.xml I got the following error: [INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing null with /home/.../MyApp/target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.pom
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] Error creating shaded jar: null.   So obviously that solution does not work. Will try the second option.  Stephen, I am not sure I followed what you meant in your comment "one artifact per module... don't hijack your aggregator" - You don't mean adding this plugin for every module's pom.xml, right? Will try to add an "uber-project" with dependency to MyApp.

Answer (score 0):

The solution approach that works in such environments is hierarchical aggregation. So, first create a single jar for subAppPomAggregationProject by 
creating say subAppPomAggregationProject.aggregate maven project, and in its pom specify all subAppPomAggregationProject modules as dependencies, 
and add the maven-assembly plugin:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
         <configuration>
             <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
             <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
             </descriptors>
             <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
             </descriptorRefs>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>]
```

Then do the same at the app level - where the created subAppPomAggregationProject aggregation jar is one of the modules!

Because at each level the conflicts between dependencies are resolved, none of the dependencies then pose conflicts in the next level up aggregation 
(as they already appear relative in their single jar... or something along those lines :-)).